# Can you surpress the "Type: EXEC" and "Type: DONE" output when using doSNOW and foreach in R?

Tags: r, logging, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach, snow

I'm using doSnow and foreach to send a bunch of messages in parallel, but they are cluttering my logs making them difficult to parse. The simple example below:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

numbers <- 1:6
cool_print <- function(x) print(paste0(x, " is cool"))
cl <- makeCluster(2, outfile="") # "" passes messages to standard out 
registerDoSNOW(cl)
sns_responses <-
    foreach(
      x        = numbers
      ) %dopar% {
        cool_print(x)
      }
 stopCluster(cl)
```

Outputs the following:

```
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
[1] "1 is cool"
[1] "2 is cool"
Type: EXEC 
[1] "3 is cool"
Type: EXEC 
[1] "4 is cool"
Type: EXEC 
[1] "5 is cool"
Type: EXEC 
[1] "6 is cool"
>  stopCluster(cl)
Type: DONE 
Type: DONE
```

I just want it to print all of the " is cool" statements.

Can you do this? Is there an option I can set in Snow somewhere that allows printing, but not this other stuff?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible - the message is printed unconditionally by a function in the `snow` package ([source code](https://github.com/cran/snow/blob/master/R/snow.R#L44)).

Comment: Not that it makes a difference here, but if you don't have specific reasons for using the 'snow' package, I recommend that you move to the 'parallel' package instead.  The 'snow' package was basically incorporated as-is into the 'parallel' in R 2.14.0, and 'snow' can more or less be considered "deprecated" these days.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment [Why don't parallel jobs print in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308162/why-dont-parallel-jobs-print-in-rstudio/62315478#62315478) for why using `outfile = ""` is most likely *not* a solution - it's more of a hack that doesn't really work.

Below is a solution using the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework (disclaimer: I'm the author) that resembles your example as close as possible and at the same time relays the output produced on the workers to the main R process:

```r
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
plan(cluster, workers=cl)

cool_print <- function(x) print(paste0(x, " is cool"))

numbers <- 1:6
sns_responses <- foreach(x=numbers) %dopar% {
  cool_print(x)
}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that the output is relayed only when a worker is finished with its task and always the in order as you would when running it sequentially, so there's a delay.  If you're after *progress updates*, you can use the [progressr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=progressr) package (disclaimer: I'm also the author here), e.g.

```r
library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(progressr)
registerDoFuture()

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
plan(cluster, workers=cl)

cool_print <- function(x) print(paste0(x, " is cool"))

numbers <- 1:6

with_progress({
  p <- progressor(along=numbers)             
  sns_responses <- foreach(x=numbers) %dopar% {
    p(paste0(x, " is cool"))
    cool_print(x)
  }
})

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not working on the local machine, that can cause this problem. Try to change outfile to ‘/dev/null’. Check documentation:

> "Where to direct the stdout and stderr connection output from the workers. "" indicates no redirection (which may only be useful for workers on the local machine). Defaults to ‘/dev/null’ (‘nul:’ on Windows). The other possibility is a file path on the worker's host. Files will be opened in append mode, as all workers log to the same file."